# Top of scrollable div not visible

Tags: html, css

I need to add a vertically scrollable div in my project. The div is a list of items with fixed height. I can't figure out why the top area of the div is not visible. Below is some sample code. As you can see, the first element of the list is not entirely visible.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #85ffbd 0%, #fffb7d 100%);
}

.content {
  width: 75%;
  max-height: 500px;

  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.post-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;


  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  width: 95%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.post-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.test {
  height: 8rem;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Some list</h1>
    
    <div class="post-list">

      <div class="post-item"> <div class="test"> 1. some content </div> </div>
      <div class="post-item"> <div class="test"> 2. some content </div> </div>
      <div class="post-item"> <div class="test"> 3. some content </div> </div>
      <div class="post-item"> <div class="test"> 4. some content </div> </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1dphx94s/8/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just remove `justify-content: center` in `post-list` it places all the content in the center of div and makes huge struggling which is not necessary in our case, you just need to center elements on X-axis, `flex` and `align-items` are enough

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #85ffbd 0%, #fffb7d 100%);
}

.content {
  width: 75%;
  max-height: 500px;

  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.post-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  /*justify-content: center;*/


  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  width: 95%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.post-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.test {
  height: 8rem;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Some list</h1>
    
    <div class="post-list">

      <div class="post-item"> <div class="test"> 1. some content </div> </div>
      <div class="post-item"> <div class="test"> 2. some content </div> </div>
      <div class="post-item"> <div class="test"> 3. some content </div> </div>
      <div class="post-item"> <div class="test"> 4. some content </div> </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That actually makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In my case there is no justify-content:center;, what can be thecase?

Comment: @ViditVarshney depends on code what you have written

Comment: @callmenikk pls take a look at the feedback section on https://www.frontendmentor.io/solutions/resultssummarycomponentsolution-RjGNVaT__v